# Ionic & Angular: Inserting Function Names with ngFor

Tags: arrays, angular, ionic-framework, ngfor, function-call

How can I insert a function call via *ngFor, while this call comes as an inserted String from the Array I'm iterating over?

My array contains a list of user actions that are described by their function names (among others). The template has a part that shall list these actions for each user entry, using Ionic's `ion-fab` directive. Instead of writing down each action I want to iterate over the list using `*ngFor` and insert each function name into a `(click)` attribute.
My current solution doesn't work, though.

Here's my code:

**Class**

```
constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private usersProv: Users
) {
    this.userActions = [
        {
            'label'     : 'Edit',
            'function'  : 'editUser',
            'icon'      : 'ios-create-outline',
            'color'     : 'primary'
        },
        {
            'label'     : 'Remove',
            'function'  : 'removeUser',
            'icon'      : 'ios-trash-outline',
            'color'     : 'yellow'
        },
        {
            'label'     : 'Send message',
            'function'  : 'sendMessageToUser',
            'icon'      : 'ios-send-outline',
            'color'     : 'secondary'
        }
    ];
    console.info('userActions', this.userActions);
}
```

**Template**

```
<ion-fab right>
    <button ion-fab mini color="light">
        <ion-icon name="ios-arrow-dropleft"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-fab-list side="left">
        <div *ngFor="let action of userActions">
            <button ion-fab mini color="{{action.color}}" title="{{action.label}}" (click)="action.function(user)">
                <ion-icon name="{{action.icon}}"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </div>
    </ion-fab-list>
</ion-fab>
```

And this is the error I get:

```
ERROR TypeError: "_v.context.$implicit.function is not a function"
```

Inserting with curly brackets (`(click)="{{action.function}}(user)"`) doesn't help, either. The error then is:

```
`ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{action.function}}(user)]`
```

Is this possible at all?
And is it recommendable to approach it the way I'm doing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of a string, hold a reference to the function, so `'function'  : this.editUser` for example. Note that there are no parentheses, as we want a reference to the function, not to invoke it

Comment: As @user184994 says want a function, not a string. You cannot call a string, as in `"f"(1)`, in JavaScript or in an Angular template.

Comment: Why don't you create a method like `executeAction(action:string, user: any): void` and inside call the right method using `switch(action){ case 'editUser': this.editUser(user); break; ... }`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a string, you should hold a reference to the function, like so

```
userActions = [
    {
        'label'     : 'Edit',
        'function'  : this.editUser.bind(this),
        'icon'      : 'ios-create-outline',
        'color'     : 'primary'
    },
    {
        'label'     : 'Remove',
        'function'  : this.removeUser.bind(this),
        'icon'      : 'ios-trash-outline',
        'color'     : 'yellow'
    },
    {
        'label'     : 'Send message',
        'function'  : this.sendMessageToUser.bind(this),
        'icon'      : 'ios-send-outline',
        'color'     : 'secondary'
    }
];
```

Here I'm using `bind`, so we don't lose the context of `this` when we invoke the function.

Then, in your HTML, you can call it like so:

```
<button (click)="a.function(user)">{{a.label}}</button>
```

**[Here is a StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sg9enb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use @user184994's solution, bind `this` context and use a reference, but if you still wanting to use strings, you can get access to component's methods via `this['methodName'](parameter)`, in my example it looks like `this[a.function](user)`.

Here is a [**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xxqzt5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: Just watch out for minification / uglification in the build, as the function name may be changed and `this[a.function]` will be undefined

Comment: @user184994, are you sure? `a.function` is an object property, will it be minifyed only in component, and in template it will not? I always thought, that object properties are untouchable in default webpack build for angular.

Comment: So `a.function` will  still be set to `methodName`, but the method itself has been uglified, and is now called `x` to save bytes, therefore `this[a.function]` is looking for `this.methodName`, which no longer exists

Comment: @user184994, by the way, we use the following structure in current project and it works fine with both dev and prod builds for a long time, so looks like the uglyfication is safe, we haven't got any errors with this part

Comment: Ah okay, that's worth knowing. I thought that the build process uglified the TS class function names as part of the build, but I've just checked and as you say its fine

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. At the moment, Strings are not needed, so I switched to references as described by @user184994. I'll keep your solution in mind, though, as well as the other comments in this regard, in case we need to switch back to Strings for some reason.